# How to to tokenize sentence using javascript

Tags: javascript, split, tokenize

I'm trying to tokenize following sentence using JavaScript split function.

```
  CHRIS NISWANDEE,
   (SMALLSYS INC,
   795 E DRAGRAM),
   TUCSON AZ 85705,
   USA
```

my expected result is,

```
 "chris","niswnadee",",","(","smallsys","inc","785","e","dgram","("...
etc
```

Im able to split at word boundries using following code,

```
"CHRIS NISWANDEE, (SMALLSYS INC, 795 E DRAGRAM), TUCSON AZ 85705, USA".split(/\b\s+/)
```

is there any way i can get those commas and parenthesizes in my result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you want to split on `/\s+|\b/` maybe.

It means: "any sequence of whitespace (`\s+`) **or** (`|`) any word boundary (`\b`)"

```
"CHRIS NISWANDEE, (SMALLSYS INC, 795 E DRAGRAM), TUCSON AZ 85705, USA".split(/\s|\b/)
```

Output

```
["CHRIS", "NISWANDEE", ",", "(", "SMALLSYS", "INC", ",", "795", "E", "DRAGRAM", "),", "TUCSON", "AZ", "85705", ",", "USA"]
```